# How is it used translated messages inside a Haskell file?

Tags: haskell, internationalization, yesod

I have searched in internet, in the Yesod Web ebook and other tutorials ([Yesod Tutorial](http://tutorial-yesod-haskell.computer-mind.com/static/tutorial/yesod_tutorial.html)) but I have not been able to clarify this problem. I am using the scaffolded site.

I have a handler, inside it returns a value, the email if the user is authenticated or a string if he is not. What I want is to return the localized message instead the string "(Unknown User ID)". My problem is to use a value from the message file (ex. MsgHello), if I do this, it returns errors like:

> Couldn't match expected type `AppMessage' with actual type`Text'

I have tried using **(show MsgHello)** or **(pack MsgHello)**, even calling **msg <- getMessageRender** but I have not been able to do what I expect. If you have any suggestions, they are welcome.

Thanks!!

PD: This is part of the code that I am working on, line :

```
getUserProfileR :: Handler RepHtml
getUserProfileR = do        
    maid <- maybeAuth
    let user = case maid of
                    Nothing -> "(Unknown User ID)"
                    Just (Entity _ u) -> userEmail u
    defaultLayout $ do
        setTitleI MsgUserProfile
        $(widgetFile "nhUserProfile")
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Tickhon Jelvis for pointing out those web pages, also I found this one: [Poly Hamlet i18n](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2011/05/non-poly-hamlet-i18n) where I was able to get the solution to the problem.

So, if I would like to use a localized message, I would do:

```
getUserProfileR :: Handler RepHtml
getUserProfileR = do        
    maid <- maybeAuth
    msg <- getRenderMessage
    let user = case maid of
                    Nothing -> msg MsgNoUser --"(Unknown User ID)"
                    Just (Entity _ u) -> userEmail u
    defaultLayout $ do
        setTitleI MsgUserProfile
        $(widgetFile "nhUserProfile")
```

Also remember that there is a helper function "setTitleI" which takes directly a Msg value and avoids the use of "msg MsgThisPageTitle"

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of the `I18N` module is that you want to take your `AppMessage` value and use [`renderMessage`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/shakespeare-i18n/latest/doc/html/Text-Shakespeare-I18N.html#t%3aRenderMessage) on it.

You need to pass in a type specifying your translation type and a list of languages as well as your message. The translation type is created using the [`mkMessage`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/shakespeare-i18n/latest/doc/html/Text-Shakespeare-I18N.html#v%3amkMessage) function and the list of languages looks something like `["en-US", "en-GB", "fr"]`.